# How to use JPA annotations in ormlite?

Tags: jpa, ormlite

I would like to use JPA annotations in ormlite. These annotations (like @Entity or @Id) belong to the javax.persistence package which is apparently not provided with ormlite. I could not get JPA annotations resolved, whereas ormlite specific annotations (like @DatabaseTable) are ok. Do I need to download a third party jar in order to get JPA annotations working in ormlite ?

I need to work with ormlite + JPA only.

When having a look at http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/index-all.html we can see that there are no JPA annotations documented nor available, although they are described in the user manual.

Thanks a lot in advance !!!

Answer (score 4):

javax.persistence is available in a jar from the [central maven repository](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec/1.1/geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec-1.1.jar) (for example).  It contains all annotations as well as all of the other JPA stuff that ORMLite ignores.

Answer (score 0):

[CMobileCom JPA](http://cmobilecom.com) is a new implementation of JPA specification for both Java JDBC and Android. It is light-weight, about 380K. You can add the following gradle dependencies:

Android:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("com.cmobilecom:cmobilecom-jpa-android:${version}@aar") {
        transitive = true
    }

    annotationProcessor "com.cmobilecom:cmobilecom-jpa-processor:$version"
}
```

Java JDBC:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.cmobilecom:cmobilecom-jpa-jdbc:$version"
    
    // annotation processor: generate static metamodel
    compileOnly "com.cmobilecom:cmobilecom-jpa-processor:$version"
}
```

JPA annotations are supported, so you do not need to add another jar to resolve JPA annotations in your code.

See Developer Guide:

https://cmobilecom.com/docs/jpa/latest/devguide/index.html

Disclaimer: I am a developer of [CMobileCom JPA](http://cmobilecom.com).